# Type Mismatch Required: Collection<User> Found : List<User>?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val list = arrayListOf<Users>()

 vm.users.observe(this, Observer { it:List<Users>!
            if (!it.isNullOrEmpty()){**strong text**
                list.addAll(it)
                originalList.addAll(it)
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
    })

private fun findUsers(query: String) {

    vm.searchUsers(query).observe(this, Observer { it:List<Users?>
        if (!it.isNullOrEmpty()){
            list.clear()
            list.addAll(it)  **ERROR**
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    })
}
```

Getting Error: Type Mismatch Required: Collection Found : List?

Code is to Search for the Users in Mvvm

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTHmn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Adding collection of `Nullable` type to `Non-Nullable` type, do `filterNotNull` before adding

```
vm.searchUsers(query).observe(this, Observer { it:List<Users?>
        if (!it.isNullOrEmpty()){
            list.clear()
            list.addAll(it.filterNotNull()) 
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    })
```